# Bulk data deletion query is getting timeout

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table `dbo.Logs` in SQL Server in which I am storing application logs, More than 100k rows are getting generated daily on this table. So I have written a job to delete the data periodically from the table.

I am simply using SQL DELETE query to delete data from the Logs table. When there is too many rows in the table (approx. 2,000,000) then this `DELETE` statement query is getting **timeout** from SQL SERVER management studio.

Does anyone have idea to fix the issue, I tried increasing the query timeout but the same is not working.

Comment: I suggest using metric units rather than `LAC` which not everyone understands.

Answer (score 2):

Delete them in chunks that don't cause a timeout.

For example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @r INT = 1;
 
WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 
  DELETE TOP (100000) 
  FROM dbo.Logs
  WHERE CreatedAt < DATEADD(month,-3, DATEADD(day,1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())));
 
  SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```